# r data.table dcast error message is unclear

Tags: r, data.table

My data table `comb` (`dput` output below) has the structure below. I want to dcast it like this

```
comb_wide <- dcast(comb, scenarios + qName + hemName ~ PWC_cutoff, value.var = sum)
```

R returns this error message

```
Error in setattr(ans, "names", c(lhsnames, allcols)) : 
  'names' attribute [7] must be the same length as the vector [3]
```

I can't figure out what attribute 7 and vector 3 refer to.

```
> str(comb)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  96 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ scenarios : chr  "historical_1991_2010" "ssp126_2041_2060" "ssp126_2081_2100" "ssp585_2041_2060" ...
 $ qName     : chr  "q1" "q1" "q1" "q1" ...
 $ hemName   : Factor w/ 2 levels "NH","SH": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ sum       : num  0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PWC_cutoff: num  20 20 20 20 20 20 40 40 40 40 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

dput output

```
structure(list(scenarios = c("historical_1991_2010", "ssp126_2041_2060", 
"ssp126_2081_2100", "ssp585_2041_2060", "ssp585_2081_2100", "aglabor", 
"historical_1991_2010", "ssp126_2041_2060", "ssp126_2081_2100", 
"ssp585_2041_2060", "ssp585_2081_2100", "aglabor", "historical_1991_2010", 
"ssp126_2041_2060", "ssp126_2081_2100", "ssp585_2041_2060", "ssp585_2081_2100", 
"aglabor", "historical_1991_2010", "ssp126_2041_2060", "ssp126_2081_2100", 
"ssp585_2041_2060", "ssp585_2081_2100", "aglabor", "historical_1991_2010", 
"ssp126_2041_2060", "ssp126_2081_2100", "ssp585_2041_2060", "ssp585_2081_2100", 
"aglabor", "historical_1991_2010", "ssp126_2041_2060", "ssp126_2081_2100", 
"ssp585_2041_2060", "ssp585_2081_2100", "aglabor", "historical_1991_2010", 
"ssp126_2041_2060", "ssp126_2081_2100", "ssp585_2041_2060", "ssp585_2081_2100", 
"aglabor", "historical_1991_2010", "ssp126_2041_2060", "ssp126_2081_2100", 
"ssp585_2041_2060", "ssp585_2081_2100", "aglabor", "historical_1991_2010", 
"ssp126_2041_2060", "ssp126_2081_2100", "ssp585_2041_2060", "ssp585_2081_2100", 
"aglabor", "historical_1991_2010", "ssp126_2041_2060", "ssp126_2081_2100", 
"ssp585_2041_2060", "ssp585_2081_2100", "aglabor", "historical_1991_2010", 
"ssp126_2041_2060", "ssp126_2081_2100", "ssp585_2041_2060", "ssp585_2081_2100", 
"aglabor", "historical_1991_2010", "ssp126_2041_2060", "ssp126_2081_2100", 
"ssp585_2041_2060", "ssp585_2081_2100", "aglabor", "historical_1991_2010", 
"ssp126_2041_2060", "ssp126_2081_2100", "ssp585_2041_2060", "ssp585_2081_2100", 
"aglabor", "historical_1991_2010", "ssp126_2041_2060", "ssp126_2081_2100", 
"ssp585_2041_2060", "ssp585_2081_2100", "aglabor", "historical_1991_2010", 
"ssp126_2041_2060", "ssp126_2081_2100", "ssp585_2041_2060", "ssp585_2081_2100", 
"aglabor", "historical_1991_2010", "ssp126_2041_2060", "ssp126_2081_2100", 
"ssp585_2041_2060", "ssp585_2081_2100", "aglabor"), qName = c("q1", 
"q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", 
"q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", 
"q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", 
"q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", 
"q1", "q1", "q1", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", 
"q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", 
"q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", 
"q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", 
"q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3", "q3"), hemName = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("NH", 
"SH"), class = "factor"), sum = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 746051, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 35, 746051, 0, 141, 341, 598, 25672, 746051, 50171, 72535, 
75671, 82293, 200119, 746051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 137649, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 137649, 0, 0, 0, 7, 26595, 137649, 39501, 54149, 54192, 
62361, 92355, 137649, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 746051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28991, 
746051, 3909, 63236, 75858, 99751, 341094, 746051, 365996, 462080, 
464957, 488522, 569331, 746051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 137649, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 137649, 0, 1, 2, 110, 8023, 137649, 14720, 18365, 18447, 
21514, 35848, 137649), PWC_cutoff = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 80, 80, 80, 80, 
80, 80, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 60, 60, 
60, 60, 60, 60, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 80, 80, 80, 80, 
80, 80, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 60, 60, 
60, 60, 60, 60, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80)), row.names = c(NA, -96L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x13783aee0>)
```

Comment: `value.var` should be a column, not a function

Comment: Issues like this is better to report to GitHub issue tracker of the project

Comment: The comment from @dww put me on the right track. I changed the name of the sum column to sumvals and the formula as well. An easy fix to an obvious (in hindsight) problem.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in a comment by [dww](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2761575/dww) , the column name '`sum`' confused dcast. I changed the column name to `sumvals` and the dcast statement to

```
comb_wide <- dcast(comb, scenarios + qName + hemName ~ PWC_cutoff, value.var = "sumvals")
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to put the last term into quotes, so try this one:

```
comb_wide <- dcast(comb, scenarios + qName + hemName ~ 
                   PWC_cutoff,value.var = 'sum')
```